# Produce several file outputs within one calculation

Tags: differential-equations, export

I have a differential equation which I solve with `NDSolve`. With the obtained solution I calculate some quantity. Then a constant in the ODE will be raised (until a given maximum) and the procedure repeated. Afterwards the results will be written in a data file in form of a table with two columns.

Now, if the above mentioned calculation is finished, I would like to raise another constant in the ODE and repeat the calculation, but writing the result in another data file.

I think my code won't help much, but nevertheless I can show it to make the point clearer.

```
end = 10000;

dataj = Table[{10^(i), N[ArcTan[(v/(2*alpha)*end*(

            With[{l = j}, 
             D[SphericalBesselJ[l, x], {x, 
                1}] /. {x -> (v/(2*alpha)*end)}]) -  (end*
              y'[end]/(y[end]) - 1)  *  
           With[{l = j}, 
            SphericalBesselJ[l, v/(2*alpha)*end]])/(v/(2*alpha)*end*(

            With[{l = j}, 
             D[SphericalBesselY[l, x], {x, 
                1}] /. {x -> (v/(2*alpha)*end)}]) -  (end*
              y'[end]/(y[end]) - 1)  *  
           With[{l = j}, SphericalBesselY[l, v/(2*alpha)*end]])], 
      50] /. With[{epsilon = 10^(-2), v = N[10 * 10^(3)/(299792458)], 
       alpha = 0.01, mchi = 200, mphi = 10^(i), l = j}, 
      First@NDSolve[{y''[
            x] + ((v/(2*alpha))^2 + 1/(x)*Exp[-mphi*x/(mchi*alpha)] - 
              l (l + 1)/(x^2) )*y[x] == 0, y[epsilon] == 1, 
         y'[epsilon] == (l + 1)/(epsilon)}, y, {x, 0, end}, 
        MaxSteps -> 10^(16)]]}, {i, -3, 1, .01}];
Export["PATH/testj.dat", dataj];
```

So, it would be nice to let `j` run from $0$ to `value`>0 and write the results in the respective data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` should be your friend here. Perhaps you could use something along the lines of the following:

```
alloutput = Table[
    {j, yourOriginalTableCodeAbove},
    {j, firstJvalue, lastJvalue, step}
  ];

Export["PATH/test" <> ToString[#1] <> ".dat", #2, "Table"] & @@@ alloutput
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use `MapIndexed` for this?

It looks like your data has the form

```
d = {{d11,d12},{d21,d22},{d31,d32},...},
```

correct?

If so, you could try

```
MapIndexed[
Export["test" <> ToString@#2[[1]] <> ".dat", #1] &, d]
```

`MapIndexed` lets you `Map` any function onto a list, but also provides the `Index` of each element as an additional argument to your function, accessible via `#2` (`#1` is the list entry itself).

Here, we use `MapIndexed` to extract the position of each answer in your dataset, `d`. `#2` gives you `{1}` for the first element, `{2}` for the second element, et c., so we use `[[1]]` to get rid of the braces by extracting the first (and only) part of the "list". The net effect of this is to apply `Export` to the `i`th entry of `d` and name it `testi.dat`.